# Applying an aggregate function over multiple different slices

Tags: r, aggregate, data.table

I have a data array that contains some information about people and projects as such:

```
person_id | project_id | action | time
--------------------------------------
        1 |          1 |      w |    1
        1 |          2 |      w |    2
        1 |          3 |      w |    2
        1 |          3 |      r |    3
        1 |          3 |      w |    4
        1 |          4 |      w |    4
        2 |          2 |      r |    2
        2 |          2 |      w |    3
```

I'd like to augment this data with a couple of more fields called "first_time" and "first_time_project" that collectively identify first time any action by that person was seen and the first time that developer saw any action on the project. In the end, the data should look like this:

```
person_id | project_id | action | time | first_time | first_time_project
------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1 |          1 |      w |    1 |          1 |                  1
        1 |          2 |      w |    2 |          1 |                  2
        1 |          3 |      w |    2 |          1 |                  2
        1 |          3 |      r |    3 |          1 |                  2
        1 |          3 |      w |    4 |          1 |                  2
        1 |          4 |      w |    4 |          1 |                  4
        2 |          2 |      r |    2 |          2 |                  2
        2 |          2 |      w |    3 |          2 |                  2
```

My naive way of doing this to write a couple of loops:

```
for (pid in unique(data$person_id)) {
    data[data$pid==pid, "first_time"] = min(data[data$pid==pid, "time"])
    for (projid in unique(data[data$pid==pid, "project_id"])) {
        data[data$pid==pid & data$project_id==projid, "first_time_project"] = min(data[data$pid==pid & data$project_id==projid, "time"]
    }
}
```

Now, it doesn't take a genius to see that this is going to be glacially slow with the doubly nested loops. However, I can't figure out a way to handle this in R. I'm kinda emulating the group by option for SQL. I know that by might be able to help, but I can't figure out how to do multiple slices.

Any hints on how to take my code from glacially slow to something a bit faster? I'd be happy with a snail right now.

Comment: Could you please articulate the questions more clearly? From what I understand, first_time is the min(time) when a person committed any action, right? If so then your result table doesn't make sense. Person 2 did nothing in time 1.

Comment: You're right, I had a typo in the pasted data. I've corrected it and made it bit clearer how the values are supposed to be aggregated. Thanks for the catch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `ave` :

```
transform(data, 
   first_time = ave(time, person_id, FUN = min),
   first_time_project = ave(time, person_id, project_id, drop = TRUE, FUN = min)
)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for. It took the execution time down from 1123 seconds to 0.427 seconds. Thanks for the 2630x speedup. I'm still evaluating the performance of the plyr suggestions, but yours certainly seems VERY promising.

Answer (score 4):

The combination of Hadley's plyr and transform() is powerful. If I correctly understand your question, then:

```
foo <- ddply(foo, .(person_id), transform, first_time=min(time))
foo <- ddply(foo, .(person_id, project_id), transform, 
  first_time_project=min(time))
```

Comment: Very useful and clean. I'll have to explore plyr some more in the future. This code took 65 seconds, which is a 17x speedup. Excellent, but not quite as nice as fast the accepted solution from G. Grothendieck. On the bright side, you've introduced me to plyr.

Answer (score 3):

If speed is what you are looking for, then `data.table` is the way to go.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(foo)
DT[, first_time := min(time), by = person_id]
DT[, first_time_project := min(time), by = list(person_id, project_id)]
```

Comment: Is it possible to do a nested aggregation directly, without requiring intermediate variable?

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution with no loops

```
library(plyr)


# function to get first time by any person/project
fp <- function(dat) 
{
dat$first_time=min(dat$time)
ftp <- function(d) { d$first_time_project=min(d$time); return (d) }
dat=ddply(dat, .(project_id), ftp)
return (dat)
}


#this single call should give you the result you want
result=ddply(data, .(person_id), fp)
```

Comment: plyr seems to be slightly magical. Your solution finished in 54 seconds, which is a 21x speedup. You've also taught me a little about how to add arbitrary function calls to plyr. Neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A quick way I can think of:

```
foo <- data.frame(
       person_id=rep(1:5,each=6),
       project_id=sample(1:5,30,T),
       time=sample(1:30))

first_time <- aggregate(foo$time, list(foo$person_id), min)

foo$first_time <- first_time[ match(foo$person_id,first_time[,1]),2]

bar <- subset(foo, time==first_time)

foo$first_time_project <- bar$project_id[match(foo$person_id, bar$person_id)]
```

Comment: This is close, but it doesn't quite function how I'd hoped. It accurately calculates first_time, but does not calculate first_time_project as desired. Instead it does the helpful thing of setting first_time_project to the project_id that has the lowest time for each person_id. What I was looking for was for first_time_project to be the minimum for each combination or person_id, project_id.