# Two dataframes in R: How to match multiple columns by row to find another row value

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, nested-loops, tidyverse

Rather than doing a nested for loop like this:

```
    for (rowAll in 1:nrow(groupDataUnadjusted)) {
      year <- groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, "year"]
      income  <- groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, "income_group"]
      joint  <- groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, "Joint"]
      child  <- groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, "children"]

      for (rowPuf in 1:nrow(nationalPuf)) {
        yearPuf <- nationalPuf[rowPuf, "year"]
        incomePuf  <- nationalPuf[rowPuf, "income_group"]
        jointPuf  <- nationalPuf[rowPuf, "Joint"]
        childPuf  <- nationalPuf[rowPuf, "children"]

        if ((year == yearPuf) && (income == incomePuf) && (joint == jointPuf) && (child == childPuf)) {
          groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, 'tax_difference_pct'] <- groupDataUnadjusted[rowAll, 'tax_difference_pct']   + nationalPuf[rowPuf, 'diff']
          break
        }
      }
    }
    groupDataAdjusted <- groupDataUnadjusted
```

I feel like there must be a faster way to find the corresponding rows between two dataframes. I am matching by taking to dataframes, different lengths, and looking where three columns are the same. If they are the same, I know that row is a match between them. Then I take one value from that row and add it to a value in the other dataframe.

But there must be a better way in R.

Comment: Example data please.

Comment: @CCurtis it's not necessary. This is a general case.

Comment: You cannot really expect an answer without an example, an answer is usually very contextually dependent.

Comment: @zacdav I disagree. This is such a simple query pattern. It's obvious from my example code. I'm matching on a few columns to try to find another column.

Comment: Obvious to you as the person with all the information sure. You've taken something that contextually makes sense to you and abstracted it to a general question. A specific code example with a non-specific question. To be honest you can google " way to find the corresponding rows between two dataframes" and find the answer as the first link.

Comment: @zacdavYou are completely wrong and I'll leave it at that. And from your "to be honest" you make it clear it's a simple question -- like I said.

Comment: Actually, an example would help here, as in addition to joining, you are also aggregating the `diff` variable over groups that match in both data frames.

Comment: @Alex It wouldn't help but isn't necessary. The downvotes are uncalled for.

Comment: @incodeveritas exactly my point. A simple question should not have an abstracted example especially if this is something you could have just googled to solve. Particularly in data manipulation, a clear example is everything. Don't sit here and think that every person voting here is wrong.

Comment: or this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031116/joining-aggregated-values-back-to-the-original-data-frame

Comment: Anyway, joining data frames has been extensively covered on this site, as well as aggregation by groups. With small datasets the order should not matter.

Comment: @Alex. Great feel free to close. In the past you could delete a question like this.. even with an answer. You no longer can.

Answer (score 1):

you can use join functions from dplyr

Depending if you want to keep all rows or just the ones with a match probably

```
library(dplyr)
groupDataAdjusted  <- left_join(groupDataUnadjusted, nationalPuf, by = c("year", "income_group","Joint","children") %>% 
                            mutate(tax_difference_pct = tax_difference_pct + diff)
```

Note this is untested as you did not provide reproducible data, but should give you the idea.

If these are the only matching column names you don't have to specify "by"

or use full_join to keep all rows

See top right of 2nd page of this:
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf

Comment: The DFs are different lengths.

Comment: it doesnt matter if they are different lengths

Comment: Different lengths shouldn't matter in a join. If this doesn't give then desired output then I'd need example data to better explain your desired output

Comment: you probably want: `groupDataAdjusted  <- left_join(groupDataUnadjusted, nationalPuf, by = c("year", "income_group","Joint","children") %>% group_by(year, income_group, Joint, children) %>%
                            summarise(tax_difference_pct = tax_difference_pct[1] + sum(diff, na.rm = T)) %>% ungroup`. This assumes that the grouping variables define unique rows in `groupDataUnadjusted`.