# R - Sum Values in column

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I'm currently stuck with below problem,
scenario:

> I have two columns who together serves as a "Primary key, and column
>   with values that i want to sum. Whats important, I want summed values
>   to be copied over all records with the same "Primary key"

So it should go something like this:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 la01
A1   B1   EPP  1
A1   B2   EPP  1
A1   B1   EPQ  2
```

Trasnofrms into:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 la01
A1   B1   EPP  3
A1   B2   EPP  1
A1   B1   EPQ  3
```

I'he had some success using `group_by` with one of the `summarise` versions, but the best I've got was **results of the sum split by number of records summed**, but i need it **copied**.

Looking forward for your thoughts and answers.

Comment: You can use the `transform()` function. A useful thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031116/joining-aggregated-values-back-to-the-original-data-frame

Comment: `df[, la01 := sum(la01), by = .(Col1, Col2)]`

Answer (score 2):

You should use **mutate()** instead of **summarise()** when your dataframe is grouped. It enables you to keep the same dimension of the dataframe and to not summarise some rows.

```
df <- data.frame(Col1 = rep('A1', 3), 
                 Col2 = c('B1', 'B2', 'B1'), 
                 Col3 = c('EPP', 'EPP', 'EPQ'), 
                 la01 = c(1,1,2))

df %>% 
   group_by(Col1, Col2) %>% 
   mutate(la01 = sum(la01)) %>% 
   ungroup()

# A tibble: 3 x 4
    Col1   Col2   Col3  la01
  <fctr> <fctr> <fctr> <dbl>
1     A1     B1    EPP     3
2     A1     B2    EPP     1
3     A1     B1    EPQ     3
```

Comment: p.s. you can copy and paste tables into `fread` e.g. `df <- fread('[paste table here]')` to avoid recreating the df by hand.

Comment: Works great thank you! I guess i got lost in all the options R had.

Comment: @demarsylvain One more question, why do you add `ungroup()` at the end?

Comment: if you let the table grouped, it will impact all the next operations on the table. For instance it's impossible to remove or modify the column Col1, because it's a grouping variable. If this is what you want, we can let the table grouped, but keep it in mind.

Comment: I've tried this solution with way more information and it seems that it is collecting the value of all records and not grouping by a single value of a row. The only difference is that instead of using 2 columns on the grou_by function, I have only used 1. Will try using 2 columns ee if that changes the outcome.